# How to add new field to all documents in a collection through Mongock?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongotemplate, mongock

I have a Collection of documents that looks like:

```json
[
    {
        "firstName" : "Foo",
        "phone" : "+1 111 1111",
        "car": "Toyota"
    },
    {
        "firstName" : "Bar",
        "phone" : "+2 222 2222",
        "car": "Honda"
    }
]
```

And I want to add a new field for every document in this collection "Persons", I'm able to execute a syntax on console, but since I need the change to be stored somehow, we are using Mongock. And I can't find a way to execute a `update` trough `MongockTemplate`.
The `{ "key" : "value" }` for the documents are static, I don't even need variable to pass them, the final documents should look like:

```json
[
    {
        "firstName" : "Foo",
        "phone" : "+1 111 1111",
        "car": "Toyota",
        "species" : "human"
    },
    {
        "firstName" : "Bar",
        "phone" : "+2 222 2222",
        "car": "Honda",
        "species" : "human"
    }
]
```

I don't know how to execute a query like the one bellow, inside `MongockTemplate`:

````
db.getCollection('Persons').update(
  {},
  { $set: {"species": "human"} },
  false,
  true
)

Here's the StackTrace:

```java
22:18:48.237 [main] ERROR io.changock.runner.core.ChangockBase - Error in changock process. ABORTED MIGRATION
io.changock.migration.api.exception.ChangockException: Error in method[UpdateAddTypeField.updateAddTypeField] : 'com.mongodb.client.result.UpdateResult org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.updateMulti(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query, org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update, java.lang.String)'
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.processExceptionOnChangeSetExecution(MigrationExecutor.java:195)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.processSingleChangeSet(MigrationExecutor.java:102)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.lambda$processSingleChangeLog$2(MigrationExecutor.java:94)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.executeInTransactionIfStrategyOrUsualIfNot(MigrationExecutor.java:80)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.processSingleChangeLog(MigrationExecutor.java:94)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.lambda$processAllChangeLogs$1(MigrationExecutor.java:88)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.executeInTransactionIfStrategyOrUsualIfNot(MigrationExecutor.java:80)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.processAllChangeLogs(MigrationExecutor.java:88)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.lambda$executeMigration$0(MigrationExecutor.java:69)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.executeInTransactionIfStrategyOrUsualIfNot(MigrationExecutor.java:80)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.executeMigration(MigrationExecutor.java:69)
    at io.changock.runner.spring.v5.core.SpringMigrationExecutor.executeMigration(SpringMigrationExecutor.java:38)
    at io.changock.runner.core.ChangockBase.execute(ChangockBase.java:44)
    at io.changock.runner.spring.v5.ChangockSpringBuilderBase$ChangockSpringApplicationRunner.run(ChangockSpringBuilderBase.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:786)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:776)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at com.hiden.subhiden.project.subhidenprojecterviceApplication.main(subhidenprojecterviceApplication.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.executeChangeSetMethod(MigrationExecutor.java:174)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.executeAndLogChangeSet(MigrationExecutor.java:127)
    at io.changock.runner.spring.v5.core.SpringMigrationExecutor.executeAndLogChangeSet(SpringMigrationExecutor.java:44)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.processSingleChangeSet(MigrationExecutor.java:100)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.client.result.UpdateResult org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.updateMulti(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query, org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update, java.lang.String)'
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.springdata.v2.decorator.impl.MongockTemplate.lambda$updateMulti$53(MongockTemplate.java:383)
    at io.changock.driver.api.lock.guard.invoker.LockGuardInvokerImpl.invoke(LockGuardInvokerImpl.java:18)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.springdata.v2.decorator.impl.MongockTemplate.updateMulti(MongockTemplate.java:383)
    at com.hiden.subhiden.project.dbchangelogs.UpdateAddTypeField.updateAddTypeField(UpdateAddTypeField.java:32)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
22:18:48.315 [main] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.springdata.v2.decorator.impl.MongockTemplate.lambda$updateMulti$53(MongockTemplate.java:383)

The following method did not exist:

    'com.mongodb.client.result.UpdateResult org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.updateMulti(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query, org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update, java.lang.String)'

The method's class, org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/johnnes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate: file:/home/johnnes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate


Process finished with exit code 1
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after many tried I've came upon the following solution:
Get a instance of the MongoTemplate Impl trough the MongockTemplate and use it instead of the MongockTemplate. I've still got no ideia why it worked. If I figure it out I'll update this thread.

```java
@ChangeSet(order = "1", id = "updateData", author = "J. Souza")
  public void updateCollectionAddSpecieField(MongockTemplate mongockTemplate) {

    MongoTemplate template = mongockTemplate.getImpl();

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(where(SPECIES_FIELD).exists(false));
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set(SPECIES, HUMAN);
    UpdateResult updateResult = template
        .updateMulti(query, update, "Collection-Name");

    log.info("Matched {} | Modified {}",
        updateResult.getMatchedCount(), updateResult.getModifiedCount());
  }
```

Comment: Hello Johnnes, although that seems a temporally solution, you shouldn't be using `mongockTemplate.getImpl()` directly, your changes are not really synchronised under the Mongock lock. Probably works because your changes takes less than the the initial time the lock is taken for. But, if for any reason, your changes took longer, it could produce unexpected results.

Please, can you provide the error log when using MongockTemplate, so I can help you to figure out where the issue is?

Comment: @Mongockteam I've updated with the error log, I think I forgot to mention you here.

Comment: Thanks for the error log. We posted a new answer with what we believe is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Anything you can do with normal MongoTemplate, you can do it as well with MongockTemplate.

In this case, you can tune the UpdateOptions and some other stuff, but it can be as easy as

```java
       Document updater = new Document()
          .append("$set", new Document().append("species", "human"));
        
       mongockTemplate.getCollection("Persons")
           .updateMany(new Document(), updater);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried the aproach like you mentioned, but Mongock was keeping giving an error. I've no ideia why, since I've a other scripts that add new indexes to some of my collections and it still works fine!

Comment: We have tried that with Mongock and it works fine. Assuming Mongock is configured right, the only possibility I can think of is that you are using enabling transactions within Mongock. There are some known issues with that kind of operation and transactions

Answer (score 2):

While the previous answer is still valid, after your posted your error log, I think I found the issue. You are using incompatible versions of MongoDB Spring Data and Mongock Driver. On one side, you are using MongoDB Spring Data `3.0.5.RELEASE` and on the other side, you are using the Mongock driver `mongodb-spring-data-v2`, which is intended to be used with Spring Data 2. **You should use `mongodb-spring-data-v3` instead**.

For more information, please take a look to the [official documentation](https://www.mongock.io/quick-start).